# Scala Pattern Match Failed to match specific word

Tags: scala

I'm quite new with Scala and especially the awesome pattern match. However, I find this code not working. I created a "dictionary" that has the match words, then I use a for-comprehension so each line will be matched up with the words in the dictionary.

This is the Map used to create regex.

```
  val dictionary = Map(
    """will""" -> 1,
    """going to""" -> 2,
    """future""" -> 3
  )
```

This is the main for-loop:

```
for (
      ln <- file.getLines();
      (word, loc) <- dictionary
    ){
      val regex = word.r
      ln match {
        case regex(ln) => {totalLine += 1
          println("Match detected: " + word)
          val originalElem = doc.BOWVector(dictionary.get(ln).get)
          doc.BOWVector.updated(dictionary.get(ln).get, originalElem+1) //vector is updated
          }
        case _ => {totalLine += 1}
      }
}
```

When I use `ln.contains("will")` and it works! However the regex won't work. WHY?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little closer:

```
scala> for (ln <- List("I will go"); (word, loc) <- dictionary) {
     | val r = word.r.unanchored
     | ln match { case r() => println(s"Yes $word") ; case _ => println(s"No $word") }}
Yes will
No going to
No future
```

The default anchored regex is `^will$`.

If you want to not worry about the capturing groups, use a "sequence wildcard."

```
scala> for (ln <- List("I will go"); (word, loc) <- dictionary) {
     | val r = word.r.unanchored
     | ln match { case r(_*) => println(s"Yes $word") ; case _ => println(s"No $word") }}
Yes will
No going to
No future

scala> val dictionary = Map("wi(l*)" -> 1)
dictionary: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(wi(l*) -> 1)

scala> for (ln <- List("I will go"); (word, loc) <- dictionary) {
     | val r = word.r.unanchored
     | ln match { case r(_*) => println(s"Yes $word") ; case _ => println(s"No $word") }}
Yes wi(l*)

scala> for (ln <- List("I will go"); (word, loc) <- dictionary) {
     | val r = word.r.unanchored
     | ln match { case r(ells) => println(s"Yes $ells") ; case _ => println(s"No $word") }}
Yes ll
```

Comment: Thank you! Actually `.unanchored` made a big difference and made this program work!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `scala.util.matching.Regex.unapplySeq` returns matching groups

If regex doesn't contain groups (your case), in pattern matching it should be used in form:

```
scala> val regex1 = "foo".r
regex1: scala.util.matching.Regex = foo

scala> "foo" match { case regex1() => "match" }
res0: String = match
```

And with matching groups it will be

```
scala> val regex2 = "(foo)".r
regex2: scala.util.matching.Regex = (foo)

scala> "foo" match { case regex2(group) => s"match $group" }
res1: String = match foo
```

Number of groups can be arbitrary, but number of arguments in `case` statement should match

```
scala> val regex3 = "(foo)(\\d)".r
regex3: scala.util.matching.Regex = (foo)(\d)

scala> "foo1" match { case regex3(word, digit) => s"match $word $digit" }
res2: String = match foo 1
```

Also, see examples for [unapplySeq](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.util.matching.Regex) scaladoc

Comment: that's what I suspected! The pattern match is actually an unboxing tool instead of a simple matching (case/switch).

Comment: Emmm..for some reason I don't know, the program still didn't work.